# Don't want instance to see Python @classmethod

Tags: python, instance, class-method

I want to use `@classmethod`, but I don't want to pollute the instance's namespace with it.  If I have a class method `for_classes_only`, how do I keep the instance from getting it?

```
class MyThing(object):
    def __init__(self, this=None):
        self.this = this

    @classmethod
    def for_classes_only(cls):
        print "I have a class {}".format(cls)


thing = MyThing(this='that')
```

This is great:

```
>>> MyThing.for_classes_only()
I have a class <class '__main__.MyThing'>
```

This is annoying:

```
>>> thing.for_classes_only
<bound method type.for_classes_only of <class '__main__.MyThing'>>
```

Comment: *Everything* on a class is accessible on the instance. It doesn't *live* there, it is that Python looks at the class when attributes are not present on the instance itself. Use a function *outside the class* if you don't want instances to see it too. You'll have to pass in the class explicitly of course, as it won't be bound.

Comment: So "class method" just means that the method receives the class, not that the method is restricted to the class.  Got it.

Comment: You can't hide it but you could make its behaviour change based on whether or not the class has been instantiated, e.g. by setting a flag in `__init__`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a [metaclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python):

```
class Meta(type):
    # There is *NO* @classmethod decorator here
    def my_class_method(cls):
        print "I have a class {}".format(cls)

class MyThing(object):
    __metaclass__ = Meta
    def __init__(self, this=None):
        self.this = this
```

This is heavier magic than most people need or want, so only do this if you're really quite sure you need it.  Most of the time, a normal `@classmethod` is good enough.

Comment: You're right, this is overkill for an annoyance.  But it gets the job done:-)  I happen to be working with a metaclass, so this is just fine.  Thanks!